MATLAB Fourier: Why do I see less harmonics the more I increase the sampling frequency?
I made MATLAB calculate the Fourier transform of these square wave pulses which have a frequency of 60Hz. I do not understand why, the more I increase the sampling frequency, the less visible the harmonics are at 120Hz (2nd harmonic), 240Hz (4th harmonic.)
Here is my code.
By changing the sampling frequency fs at the line fs = 10000; % Sampling frequency in Hz I get the different plot results below:
% Parameters
% Frequency of the square wave in Hz
f = 60; 
T = 1/f; % Period of the square wave
% Duration for which the wave is generated (in seconds)
duration = 0.8; 
fs = 10000; % Sampling frequency in Hz
rise_time = 0.0000; % Rise time in seconds 0.0030
A = 5; % Desired A range from 0 to 5

% Time vector
t = 0:1/fs:duration;


% Generate square wave
square_wave = 2.5*square(2*pi*f*t);
square_wave2 = 2.5+2.5*square(2*pi*f*t);


% Create a custom square wave with specified rise time
csw = zeros(size(t));
csw2 = zeros(size(t));
 % Number of samples for the rise time
trSmpls = round(rise_time * fs);

for i = 1:length(t)
    if square_wave(i) > 0
       csw(i)=min(2.5,csw(max(i-1,1))+2.5/trSmpls);
    else
       csw(i)=max(-2.5,csw(max(i-1,1))-2.5/trSmpls);
    end
end

for i = 1:length(t)
    if square_wave2(i) > 0
        csw2(i)=min(A,csw2(max(i-1,1))+A/trSmpls);
    else
        csw2(i)=max(0,csw2(max(i-1,1))-A/trSmpls);
    end
end

% Plot the square wave
figure;

% First subplot
% Create a 2x1 grid of subplots, use the first
subplot(2, 2, 1); 
% Set the line width
plot(t, csw, 'LineWidth', 1); 
% Change font size of grid numbers
set(gca, 'FontSize', 18); 
%xlabel('Seconds', 'FontSize', 19);
ylabel('Amplitude', 'FontSize', 19);
xlabel('Seconds', 'FontSize', 19);
title('Square wave signal T=1/60s');
ylim([-3 3]); % Set y-axis limits
grid on;
yticks ([-2.5 ,0 ,2.5]);

% Second subplot
subplot(2, 2, 2); % Use the second subplot
% Plot the same square wave for illustration
plot(t, csw2, 'LineWidth', 1); 
% Change font size of grid numbers
set(gca, 'FontSize', 18); 
xlabel('Seconds', 'FontSize', 19);
ylabel('Amplitude', 'FontSize', 19);
title('Square wave, spans on positive axis T=1/60s');
ylim([-0.5 5.5]); % Set y-axis limits
grid on;
yticks ([0 ,2.5, 5]);

% Define the length for zero-padding (higher value for higher resolution)
 % Example: twice the next power of 2
nfft1 = 2^nextpow2(length(csw)*2);
nfft2 = 2^nextpow2(length(csw2)*2);

% Calculate FFT of the first square wave
Y1 = fft(csw,nfft1);
L1 = length(csw);
P2_1 = abs(Y1/L1);
P1_1 = P2_1(1:nfft1/2+1);
P1_1(2:end-1) = 2*P1_1(2:end-1);

% Calculate FFT of the second square wave
Y2 = fft(csw2,nfft2);
L2 = length(csw2);
P2_2 = abs(Y2/L2);
P1_2 = P2_2(1:nfft2/2+1);
P1_2(2:end-1) = 2*P1_2(2:end-1);

% Frequency vector
Fs = 1/(t(2)-t(1)); % Sampling frequency
f1 = Fs*(0:(nfft1/2))/nfft1;
f2 = Fs*(0:(nfft2/2))/nfft2;

% Find the indices where frequency<=330Hz
max_freq = 330;
idx1 = find(f1 <= max_freq);
idx2 = find(f2 <= max_freq);

% Plot the FFT results up to 1500 Hz
subplot(2,2,3)
plot(f1(idx1), P1_1(idx1))
set(gca, 'FontSize', 18); 
Ax = gca;
set(Ax.XAxis, 'TickValues', 0:60:300);
title('FFT of square wave signal')
xlabel('f (Hz)')
ylabel('|P1(f)|')
grid on;
xlim([0 320]); % Set x-axis limits
ylim([0 3.1]); % Set y-axis limits

%zoom xon;

subplot(2,2,4)
plot(f2(idx2), P1_2(idx2))
set(gca, 'FontSize', 18); 
Ax = gca;
set(Ax.XAxis, 'TickValues', 0:60:300);
title('FFT of Square Wave with DC component')
xlabel('f (Hz)', 'FontSize', 19)
ylabel('|P1(f)|', 'FontSize', 19)
grid on;
xlim([0 320]); % Set x-axis limits
ylim([0 3.3]); % Set y-axis limits
%zoom xon;

fs=10 000

fs=1 000

fs=600

To my knowledge, lowering the sampling frequency would mean sharper edges of the pulses so the harmonics would show up easier. Why are the Diracs at 180Hz and 300Hz always visible, while at 120Hz and 240Hz the harmonics show up on lower frequency samplings and specifically if the sampling is a multiple of 60 (which is the main harmonic.) For example, using fs=300 I get a very clean Dirac at 120Hz:


"Less visible" is good English but, "less harmonics" is bad English. In a nutshell, we use "fewer" when the subject is a plural (harmonics) and, we use "less" when the subject is singular (visible). Having said that, many native speakers get this wrong all the time.

Perfect square waves do not have even harmonics. So those even harmonics you see are an artifact from the sampling to begin with.

Right! so when you say "perfect square waves" you meant 50% duty cycle. If I Change the duty cycle I see different $n$ harmonics are zero

Yes, sure. 50% duty cycle means every second harmonic is missing. 33% duty cycle means every third harmonic is missing and so on.

@Janka was right. If I change my code to be able to change the duty cycle and span my frequency plot to see more frequencies:
% Parameters
% Frequency of the square wave in Hz
f = 60; 
duty_cycle = 100/2 % Duty cycle in percentage
% Duration for which the wave is generated (in seconds)
duration = 0.3; 
fs = 10000; % Sampling frequency in Hz (increased)
rise_time = 0.0000; % Rise time in seconds 0.0030
A = 5; % Desired A range from 0 to 5

% Time vector
t = 0:1/fs:duration;

% Generate square wave
square_wave = 2.5*square(2*pi*f*t, duty_cycle);
square_wave2 = 2.5+2.5*square(2*pi*f*t, duty_cycle);

% Create a custom square wave with specified rise time
csw = zeros(size(t));
csw2 = zeros(size(t));
% Number of samples for the rise time
trSmpls = round(rise_time * fs);

for i = 1:length(t)
    if square_wave(i) > 0
       csw(i)=min(2.5,csw(max(i-1,1))+2.5/trSmpls);
    else
       csw(i)=max(-2.5,csw(max(i-1,1))-2.5/trSmpls);
    end
end

for i = 1:length(t)
    if square_wave2(i) > 0
        csw2(i)=min(A,csw2(max(i-1,1))+A/trSmpls);
    else
        csw2(i)=max(0,csw2(max(i-1,1))-A/trSmpls);
    end
end

% Plot the square wave
figure;

% First subplot
% Create a 2x1 grid of subplots, use the first
subplot(2, 2, 1); 
% Set the line width
plot(t, csw, 'LineWidth', 1); 
% Change font size of grid numbers
set(gca, 'FontSize', 18); 
%xlabel('Seconds', 'FontSize', 19);
ylabel('Amplitude', 'FontSize', 19);
xlabel('Seconds', 'FontSize', 19);
title('Square wave signal T=1/60s');
ylim([-3 3]); % Set y-axis limits
grid on;
yticks ([-2.5 ,0 ,2.5]);

% Second subplot
subplot(2, 2, 2); % Use the second subplot
% Plot the same square wave for illustration
plot(t, csw2, 'LineWidth', 1); 
% Change font size of grid numbers
set(gca, 'FontSize', 18); 
xlabel('Seconds', 'FontSize', 19);
ylabel('Amplitude', 'FontSize', 19);
title('Square wave, spans on positive axis T=1/60s');
ylim([-0.5 5.5]); % Set y-axis limits
grid on;
yticks ([0 ,2.5, 5]);

% Define the length for zero-padding (higher value for higher resolution)
% Example: four times the next power of 2
nfft1 = 10000 * 2^nextpow2(length(csw));
nfft2 = 10000 * 2^nextpow2(length(csw2));

% Calculate FFT of the first square wave
Y1 = fft(csw,nfft1);
L1 = length(csw);
P2_1 = abs(Y1/L1);
P1_1 = P2_1(1:nfft1/2+1);
P1_1(2:end-1) = 2*P1_1(2:end-1);

% Calculate FFT of the second square wave
Y2 = fft(csw2,nfft2);
L2 = length(csw2);
P2_2 = abs(Y2/L2);
P1_2 = P2_2(1:nfft2/2+1);
P1_2(2:end-1) = 2*P1_2(2:end-1);

% Frequency vector
Fs = 1/(t(2)-t(1)); % Sampling frequency
f1 = Fs*(0:(nfft1/2))/nfft1;
f2 = Fs*(0:(nfft2/2))/nfft2;

% Find the indices where frequency<=330Hz
max_freq = 2000;
idx1 = find(f1 <= max_freq);
idx2 = find(f2 <= max_freq);

% Plot the FFT results up to 1500 Hz
subplot(2,2,3)
plot(f1(idx1), P1_1(idx1))
set(gca, 'FontSize', 18); 
Ax = gca;
set(Ax.XAxis, 'TickValues', 0:60:700);
title('FFT of square wave signal')
xlabel('f (Hz)')
ylabel('|P1(f)|')
grid on;
xlim([0 700]); % Set x-axis limits
ylim([0 3.1]); % Set y-axis limits

%zoom xon;

subplot(2,2,4)
plot(f2(idx2), P1_2(idx2))
set(gca, 'FontSize', 18); 
Ax = gca;
set(Ax.XAxis, 'TickValues', 0:60:700);
title('FFT of Square Wave with DC component')
xlabel('f (Hz)', 'FontSize', 19)
ylabel('|P1(f)|', 'FontSize', 19)
grid on;
xlim([0 700]); % Set x-axis limits
ylim([0 3.3]); % Set y-axis limits

zoom xon;

For (100/2)=50% duty cycle there is no harmonic every second harmonic:

For (100/3)=33.33% of duty cycle there is no harmonic every 3rd harmonic:

For (100/4)=25% of duty cycle there is no harmonic every 4rd harmonic:

and so on.
@robert bristow-johnson's comment in this question here is on-point and relevant as well.
